# simple_form only allow upload when file is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using the simple_form (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) library to do a file upload using Rails 4.2.5. I want to disallow file uploads unless a file is present in the form using simple_form but do not know exactly how to do this. My code is below:

```
<%= simple_form_for @business, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
            <%= f.simple_fields_for :attached_files, AttachedFile.new do |af| %>
            <%= af.input :file, as: :file, label: false %>
          <% end %>
          <%= f.button :submit,
                       'Upload File',
                       class: 'btn btn-mini btn-success hidden',
                       id: 'submit-file-upload' %>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me know if you're looking for something a little more verbose, but the simplest implementation of this is simply by adding a required field to the input statement:

```
<%= simple_form_for @business, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :attached_files, AttachedFile.new do |af| %>
        <%= af.input :file, as: :file, label: false, required: true %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.button :submit,
                   'Upload File',
                   class: 'btn btn-mini btn-success hidden',
                   id: 'submit-file-upload' %>
<% end %>
```

Additionally, you're going to want to make sure you're doing server-side validations, as they're really the only concrete validations (browser validations can always be tampered with)

```
  def create
    @business = Business.new(business_params)

    unless params[:file].nil?
      if @business.save!
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render :new
      end 
  end
```

Lastly, make sure your config file is set to handle browser validations:

```
SimpleForm.browser_validations = true
```

Comment: goddamnit i knew something as simple as required would do it haha thanks! saves me the trouble of writing javascript

Comment: I was confused at first, too. Thought I'd have to write you an entire JS block ;) cheers!

Comment: hm actually, when i plug that in to my application it still submits if you dont have anything present for some reason...

Comment: even after restarting your server?

Comment: not sure what restarting my server would do, the output that gets rendered is just the required true tag. tried it and the same thing happened, it allows submissions without the file

Comment: turns out the config for simple form didnt have browser side validations enabled...doi! always the little configurations that do you in.